# Phusion Passenger Nginx module installer can not find rack gem installed

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, redmine

I'm trying to install passenger module to my nginx web server using the passenger-install-nginx-module installer. Although the rack gem is installed the installer can't find it.

OS: Debial GNU/Linux 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Why mod-flag it just because it's not been fixed to your satisfaction??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Although the rack gem is installed, the installer can't find it."

I guess it might depend on where the gem is installed. Did you install the rack gem with `sudo gem install` or just `gem install`? If the latter, it's probably not in a path that the passenger installer is looking in. (If the former, this answer is pointless, but we might as well start with the relatively-obvious, right?)

Comment: I installed the rack gem with sudo gem install.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to build a custom nginx package (with passenger module compiled in).